# Is it possible to write two template functions as one when the only difference is the const-ness of an argument?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I have something like:

```
template <class Foob, class T>
void do_it(Foob& f, T& t) { f.proc(t); }

template <class Foob, class T>
void do_it(Foob& f, const T& t) { f.proc(t); }
```

Some `Foob`s take `const T&`s while other `Foob`s take just `T&`s, or the same `Foob` may even have two `proc`s, one for the `const` case, one for the non-`const` case, that do different things.

However, the code of `do_it` is the same: it's just `f.proc(t)`. Sometimes the code is many lines, but still identical. Is there any way to write `do_it` as just one function? Something like this, though this would clearly not work:

```
template <class Foob, class MaybeConst, class T>
void do_it(Foob& f, MaybeConst T& t) { f.proc(t); }
```

Comment: @Columbo: Not sure I understand your comment, what I said clearly wouldn't work doesn't and here is the proof: https://ideone.com/t1GS5P .

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally skipped the `T`. :) If you remove it (and the corresponding parameter declaration), you get the solution shown below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually if the `t` argument is always an lvalue then you only need the first overload! If the lvalue has type `const U`, then the template parameter `T` is deduced as `const U` and the instantiated function's second parameter type will be `const U&`, which will bind to the const lvalue just fine.

The second overload is only needed if the argument is an rvalue. But instead of making that a special case, why not just use perfect forwarding?

```
// works for both lvalues and rvalues with any cv-qualification
template <class Foob, class T>
void do_it(Foob& f, T&& t) { f.proc(std::forward<T>(t)); }
```